# Android studio wont recognize appcompat or any other default items

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-build

Today I re-opened an app(after a few months) on which I previously worked on a few months ago .But unfortunately everything seems to stop working for that app's code.
I have searched through the internet on various hacks how to solve `appcompatactivity not resolved`

r `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar not recognized`

But I seem to have combination of all weirdest errors altogether..

Here is what I got as a gift from Android Studio-

```
java compiler errors(14 errors)
resource style/Animation.AppCompat.Dialog (aka com.actech.android.frienchat:style/Animation.AppCompat.Dialog) not found.    
resource style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar (aka com.actech.android.frienchat:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar) not found.  
resource style/TextAppearance.AppCompat (aka com.actech.android.frienchat:style/TextAppearance.AppCompat) not found.    
resource style/Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat.Dialog (aka com.actech.android.frienchat:style/Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat.Dialog) not found.    
resource style/Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog (aka com.actech.android.frienchat:style/Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog) not found.    
resource style/Base.V7.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dialog (aka com.actech.android.frienchat:style/Base.V7.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dialog) not found.  
resource style/Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat (aka com.actech.android.frienchat:style/Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat) not found.  
resource style/Animation.AppCompat.Dialog (aka com.actech.android.frienchat:style/Animation.AppCompat.Dialog) not found.    
resource style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar (aka com.actech.android.frienchat:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar) not found.  
resource style/TextAppearance.AppCompat (aka com.actech.android.frienchat:style/TextAppearance.AppCompat) not found.    
resource style/Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat.Dialog (aka com.actech.android.frienchat:style/Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat.Dialog) not found.    
resource style/Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog (aka com.actech.android.frienchat:style/Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog) not found.    
resource style/Base.V7.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dialog (aka com.actech.android.frienchat:style/Base.V7.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dialog) not found.  
resource style/Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat (aka com.actech.android.frienchat:style/Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat) not found.
```

First of all I would like to clarify I have tried these following hacks-

> 1.Clean- Rebuild
>
> 2.Invalidate Cache-restart
>
> 3.Deleting .idea folder
>
> 4.Deleting the build folder
>
> 5.Changing appcompat version

**NOTHING WORKED**

Here is my build.gradle files-

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.actech.android.frienchat"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
    implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'

}
```

and

```
build.gradle(Project)

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Any help is very much appreciated(Its full proof that a few months ago I used this android project successfully on android studio)

Comment: Did you try deleting your ~/.gradle cache, ~/.idea and ~/AndroidStudio<version> caches?

Comment: I believe I have clarified all of those exclusively inmy question..that I have tried all these hacks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, After different trial and errors I found a FIX , It should be the easiest method to carry out when Nothing is working!!

Start a new Android Studio Project with Default settings..

**Then copy and replace the common contents of build.gradle(app and project) of the newly created project to the Problematic project,And sync**

Which should solve all of these kind of errors(*But be sure that you have already tried out the hacks mentioned in the question-which failed for me and Was forced to find this new Solution..*)

Hope this will help to any other Persons facing any of these issues in future.